# PayPal Express Checkout API - searchable seller-defined ID?

Tags: paypal

I am creating subscriptions using the PayPal Express Checkout API. What I want to do is add a seller-defined 36 character ID to each subscription that I can later search on.

When sending CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile, I am populating the PROFILEREFERENCE field, which shows up as the 'Invoice Number' on the Recurring Payments dashboard on the seller site.

On the TransactionSearch method, there is an INVMUM field that can be searched, but it doesn't appear this correlates with the 'Invoice Number'.

So...how can I populate the right field so I can use INVNUM to search - or is there a better solution to my problem?

Bruce

Answer (score 0):

I would setup an [Instant Payment Notification (IPN)](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/ipn/gs_IPN/) solution. That way any data for transactions will be automatically sent through your script and can be processed accordingly in real-time.

The PROFILEREFERENCE value you're sending will come back in the IPN as invoice_number, so it would be available within your IPN script.

So whatever you're doing within a TransactionSearch script, just do that in IPN instead.  Not only will give you access to the value you're after, but it will automate the entire process in real-time so you don't have to mess with TransactionSearch / GetTransactionDetails at all.